# Can you say "Please don't try to get in contact with us"

Tags: sentence

A mailbot sends some files and should notify the recipient that this mailaddress can only send and not receive messages. This notification at the moment is:

> Please don't try to get in contact with us by answering to this mail!

Is this correct or should I change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Do not reply to this email" normally gives most people the idea.